# How to loop through all image pixels then take gray scale value, 1 channel for analysis?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I basically want to loop through a gray scale image, take the single channel (CV_8UC1) value and do analysis on each value to end up with something like this:

```
if (pixel.intensityVal >= 100 && pixel.intensityVal <= 150) { 

    bitStream.add("1")
}
else if (pixel.intensityVal >= 175 && pixel.intensityVal <= 190) {

    bitStream.add("0")
}
else {

    bitStream.add("X")
}
```

And then ultimately print the "bitStream" out for verification.

Im new to OpenCV and C++ but this seems feasible, Im just not sure of the most efficient way.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your second `if` statement appears incorrect - if the intensity is less than or equal to 175, it will necessarily be less than 190.

Comment: The most efficient way is probably to make a 255-element array populated with 51 ones, 16 zeroes and the rest as Xs and call OpenCV's `LUT()` function.

Comment: Ah yes, that if statement is a typo. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll look into the LUT() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take first into account that you already have your gray scale image, otherwise you can use `cvtColor( image, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY );` to convert it or directly upload in Grayscale (see below).

You image is stored in a `cv::Mat` variable which is a matrix with the value of every pixels. Therefore it is possible to access the intensity level by reading every cell. To do that you can use the operator `.at<type>(x,y)`.

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("lenna.png", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
for(int i=0; i<img.rows; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<img.cols; j++){
         pixel.IntensityVal = img.at<cv::CV_8UC>(i,j);
         if (pixel.intensityVal >= 100 && pixel.intensityVal <= 150) { 
            bitStream.add("1")
         }
         else if (pixel.intensityVal <= 175 && pixel.intensityVal <= 190) {
           bitStream.add("0")
         }
         else {
            bitStream.add("X")
         }

        }
}
```

There are optimal ways to access matrices using pointer, but this is not the scope of the question.

Comment: Perfect! Now if I wanted to split the image into a 32x32 grid with (0,0) being the top left "box" of the image, how would I go about using your algo to go through each box individually? For example: Box (0,0) gets tested using the pixel intensity value conditionals, then box (0,1)...(n,m)

Comment: You should propose your own solution first and then we can discuss improvements.

Comment: So as per another question I asked, I was told to loop through the image with something like this:

 int operator()(int y, int x) const
 {
  int j = y * 32;
  int i = x * 32;

  auto gridBlock = cv::Rect(i, j, 32, 32);

  
  int grayVal = gridBlock(i, j, CV_8UC1);
  int num_over_threshold = cv::countNonZero(buff);

  return num_over_threshold > count_threshold ? 255 : 0;
}

But this is for thresholding and I need to take the single channel gray scale value.

Comment: I can't update my full code in the main post so sorry if that's hard to read.

Comment: You should be able to edit you first question and add this part of the code